# Is there an R function to retrieve CPU and RAM information?

Tags: r, system-information

I want to print some hardware info in my R session. I can achieve this by using the `system()` function, which in my Linux machine looks like this:

```
> system("lscpu | grep 'Model name:'")
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
> system("lsmem | grep 'Total online memory'")
Total online memory:      16G
```

I know R has functions like `Sys.info()` to provide this kind of data, but I couldn't find such a function that allows one to print CPU and RAM info.

I would really like to find one such function, as relying on `system()` is OS-dependent.

Answer (score 8):

The `benchmarkme` package has a couple of functions you may find useful, like `get_cpu()` and `get_ram()`.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! Now I just need to decide if I'm OK with adding a package to my workflow here.